# Angular, Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a' after checking 30 answers and none helped

Tags: javascript, html, angular, module, components

I'm new with Angular. After a week I do find it very poorly documented and all the tutorials out there giving you different ideas of everything. Confusing. Before you come up with the router module missing and typo solutions, I've already gone through all those.
I really hate it that I have to ask for help here, especially that there are loads of questions regarding the same issue.

I have a header module:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";

import {HeaderComponent} from "./header.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent]
})

export class HeaderModule {}
```

And header component (here my ide also complains about the HeaderComponent being declared twice, no idea why)

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'highup-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.less']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() :void {

  }
}
```

and a template

```
<header class="main-header">
  <a [routerLink]="['/']" class="logo"><b> Admin </b></a>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <a [routerLink]="['/']"  class="sidebar-toggle" role="button">
      <span class="sr-only"> Toggle Navigation </span>
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown message-menu">
          <a [routerLink]="['/']" class="dropdown-doggle">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            <span class="label labe-success">4</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li> You have 4 new messages</li>
            <li>
              <ul class="menu">
                <a [routerLink]="['/']" >
                  <div class="pull-left">
                    <img src="/dist/img/blaaa.js" alt="User Image" />
                  </div>
                  <h4>
                    Support Team
                    <small> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> </small>
                    <p> Why noy buy a new awesome highup theme ?</p>
                  </h4>
                </a>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

app module

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HeaderModule} from "./dashboard/header/header.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    HeaderModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'highup';
}
```

app-routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: So the template wants a property called `routeerLink`.  Please point out in your code where this is defined.

Comment: I've tested your code and didn't get any "routerLink" error. can you upload your project somewhere?

Comment: first cleanup you routeModules a bit. in the appRouting module you import forRoot which is fine and exports it that means you don't need to import it in app module. next header module. you only need routerModule without forRoot, since you only want to access its directive.

Comment: @Tibrogargan not sure I understand what you mean. I doubt that either the error or the code itself refers to any "routeerLink" appearance.

Comment: @Georgemff thanks for having a look. I had a feeling that something fishy going on with my Angular project or the bundling of it.  As mentioned, my ide also complains about the component being exported twice, which is not accurate. I will try to upload it somewhere later today. I'll let you know once it's there.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen thanks for checking it, I'm going to clean it up a bit. The initial of state of that code was just a simple boilerplate, all the bits added, including the forRoot, were added as solutions suggestions found in other questions around here. The code was tested by someone else, and the error didn't come up, so it's possibly my project configuration is behind.